# Text element has right padding when text wraps

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a simple `<Text>` element in my react-native application and I can't figure out what's going on with this behavior.

When I provide a longer string and the `<Text>` element wraps the text, it seems to be adding a bunch of padding to the right side of the view.

Note: I've made the `<Text>` element have a red background just so it's easier to see what's going on in this image.

[image: example]

The left button has the wrapped text, the right button does not. Only when the text wraps do I see the strange padding.

Note that I'm using `flexShrink: 1` so that my icon doesn't get stomped out by the text element.

```js
<View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
    <View style={styles.buttonContent}>
        <Grid fill={'#fff'} style={[styles.buttonIcon, {marginRight: 6}]} />
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
             Something Longer Here
        </Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingVertical: 14,
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        borderRadius: 16,
        backgroundColor: '#27292d',
        opacity: 0.90,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1},
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 1,
        elevation: 5
    },
    buttonContent: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonIcon: {
        width: 16,
        height: 16,
        flexShrink: 1
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 14,
        lineHeight: 16,
        backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
        fontFamily: 'GeezaPro',
        flexShrink: 1
    }
});
```

### Update

I've put together this small example to demonstrate the problem.

https://snack.expo.dev/72_24tf4O

When run on the web it looks like this:

[image: example web]

But when run on android, it looks like this:

[image: example android]

Comment: Have you tried explicitly mentioning padding: 0?

Comment: @AkshayShenoy are you saying i should add that to the `buttonText` style? I tried that, no change.

Comment: I tried the same code you have on snack expo and I don't have any spaces like you have

Comment: @Guku see my updates to the question. I was able to replicate it with snack expo when running on Android.